# Split the Header page into to images using CSS

Tags: css, background-image, clip-path

I am facing an issue with making the header in the main page layout split into two images from **bottom left** to **top right**. All the resources that I found are split them into two colors. However, when I want to add pictures, I could not see any result.

See the code that I did and I do not know how to remove the space between them

```
class-image-1 {
    background-image:  url(/img/imag-1-bg.png);
    height: 100vh; 
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(1px 100vh,100% 1px,311px -1px,0px 0px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 

class-image-2{
    background-image: url(/img/bg.jpg);
    height: 100vh; 
    -webkit-clip-path:  polygon(0px 100vh,100% 100vh,100% 1px);
    position: relative; 
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

I did the same code above but I got space between the images I want them in one page. Just to clearly see this image it might give you an idea.

[image]

Comment: you cannot use image with linear gradien. And can you explain more what you need to achieve ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif could you see my update question

Comment: I voted to reopen it as it's more clear, hope you will get more votes ;)  @Blazemonger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost good, you are simply doing wrong with positions. You should make them absolute position inside a container, they should behave like layers (one above the other). I also replaced the values in the clip-path with 0 and 100% so it's more generic  :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 600px;
}

.banner {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.class-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.class-image-1 {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/800/800/);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 0, 100% 0px, 0 0);
}

.class-image-2 {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/800/700/);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="class-image class-image-2">
  </div>
  <div class="class-image class-image-1">
  </div>
</div>
```